# Position div's on top of each other allowing to overflow

Tags: html, css

I have got a few div's with different background colours.

Like this:

```
<div>
 <div class="bg-blue">Blue background</div>
 <div class="bg-orange">Orange Background</div>
 <div class="bg-white">White Background</div>
 <div class="bg-gray">Gray Background</div>
</div>
```

Some css

```
.bg-blue {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  background-image: url(../img/blue.png);
}

.bg-orange, .bg-gray{
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
  background-image: url(../img/orange.png);
}

.bg-gray {
  background-image: url(../img/gray.png);
}
.bg-white {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 15%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Now I have another div with an image which I want to overlap over the div with the orange and the white background.

So now I am not sure wether I have to create this div within the orange div or just underneeth it.

How could I sove this problem?

Comment: Use the position absolute for the div to overlap and position relative to the parent div, as it contains all the divs.

Comment: ok but where does the overlap div go? Within te parent bg-orange div?

Comment: Put it inside the parent div, as a sibling of the orange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this, this is an absoulte positioned in a relative positioned div.

http://jsfiddle.net/jd9j591r/

```
<div>
  <div class="bg-blue">Blue background</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="overlap"></div>
    <div class="bg-orange">Orange Background</div>
    <div class="bg-white">White Background</div>
 </div>
 <div class="bg-gray">Gray Background</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.bg-blue {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
    background: blue;
}

.bg-orange, .bg-gray{
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    background: orange;
}

.bg-gray {
    background: gray;
}
.bg-white {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    color: #fff;
    background: white;
}

.container {position: relative;}

.overlap {position: absolute; width: 40px; height: 160px; background: red; top: 10px; left:50px}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `div` between the orange and white but since you are using `position:absolute` there won't be a problem http://jsfiddle.net/kbo5fL9d/

```
 <div class="bg-orange odd">Orange Background</div>
<div class="image"></div>
<div class="bg-white even">White Background</div>

CSS

.image{
position:absolute;
background:yellow !important;
width:100%;
height:50px;
margin-top:-30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I have in the image div an image which I want to scale?

Comment: @sanders can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `position: absolute` and `relative`, as in my example [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/dozici/4/).

Furthermore, use the `padding-top` property in percentage to make the height of the overlapping `div` fluid, as following code:

```
.overlap {position:absolute; width:100%; background-color: red; padding-top: 25%; top:24px;}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the overlapping div has got an background image which needs to scale well?